# Recording audio on WatchOS over AVAudioRecorder

Tags: swift, avfoundation, watchkit, watchos

Is there any sample code or tutorials about that? I've found that `AVAudioRecorder` supported since WatchOS 4.0 https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiorecorder. But when I am trying to use it - it records 1 second and no actual sound (just noise).

Here is my code:

```
let audioURL = self.getRecordedFileURL()
print(audioURL.absoluteString)

let settings = [
  AVFormatIDKey: Int(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC),
  AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: AVAudioQuality.high.rawValue
]

do {
  recorder = try AVAudioRecorder(url: audioURL, settings: settings)
  recorder?.delegate = self
  recorder?.record()
} catch {
  finishRecording(success: false)
}
```

Also, should I use `AudioSession` here? If yes, is it required `requestRecordPermission` and how do deal with it? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This one works:

```
    let recordingName = "audio.m4a"
    let dirPath = getDirectory()
    let pathArray = [dirPath, recordingName]
    guard let filePath = URL(string: pathArray.joined(separator: "/")) else { return }

    let settings = [AVFormatIDKey: Int(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC),
                    AVSampleRateKey:12000,
                    AVNumberOfChannelsKey:1,
                    AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: AVAudioQuality.high.rawValue
    ]

    //start recording
    do {
        audioRecorder = try AVAudioRecorder(url: filePath, settings: settings)
        audioRecorder.delegate = self
        audioRecorder.record()
    } catch {
        print("Recording Failed")
    }
func getDirectory()-> String {
    let dirPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
    return dirPath
}
```

Don't forget to add `NSMicrophoneUsageDescription` into your **phone** companion app `Info.plist`.

Comment: Yep, the problem was that I don't add `NSMicrophoneUsageDescription` to phone companion app! Another quick question - can I request microphone usage directly from Apple Watch, not from iOS Application?

Comment: @VladyslaveSemenchenko the request will appear on Apple Watch, on the first launch, even when NSMicrophoneUsageDescription is added to companion phone app Info.plist. It's the only way to do it.<br> Don't forget to mark answer as correct one.

Comment: Thank you @david-kyslenko for your help!